# preg_replace return in variable

Tags: php, regex

here I have my regexp which founds all instances of 4chan style quoting (e.g. >10, >59, >654564) and just returns it as *pattern output*. My question is, is it possible to insert my *pattern output*...

**\1**

...into PHP function.

While this is working fine:

```
$a = preg_replace('`(&gt;\d+)`i', '\1', $b);
```

Something I am looking for is not:

```
$a = preg_replace('`(&gt;\d+)`i', '".getpost('\1')."', $b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Take a look at [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function.

---

**Example [php >= 5.3.0]** (*with use of [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)*):

```
$callback = function($match) {
    return "{" . $match[1] . "}"; # do smth with match
};
$string = 'test1 &gt;1 test2 &gt;12 test3 &gt;123 test4';
echo preg_replace_callback('~(&gt;\d+)~i', $callback, $string);
```

will output:

```
test1 {&gt;1} test2 {&gt;12} test3 {&gt;123} test4
```

---

**Example [php < 5.3.0]**:

```
function replaceCallback($match) {
    return "{" . $match[1] . "}"; # do smth with match
};
$string = 'test1 &gt;1 test2 &gt;12 test3 &gt;123 test4';
echo preg_replace_callback('~(&gt;\d+)~i', 'replaceCallback', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is difficult to implement, couldn't you?

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in

Comment: @user1955864, does second example work? What PHP version do you have?